# WebGL Three.js Moving Line with DashedMaterial

Tags: three.js, line, move

I am updating the direction of some lines and arrow helpers with three.js but when I do it with a dashed line, it becomes solid.

init() code:

```
    // EARTH LINE
    var lineGeometryEarth = new THREE.Geometry();
    var vertArrayEarth = lineGeometryEarth.vertices;
    vertArrayEarth.push( new THREE.Vector3(earth.position.x,earth.position.y,earth.position.z), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0) );
    lineGeometryEarth.computeLineDistances();
    var lineMaterialEarth = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial( { color: 0x0099ff, dashSize: 2, gapSize: 2 } );
    lineEarth = new THREE.Line( lineGeometryEarth, lineMaterialEarth );
    scene.add(lineEarth);
```

update() code:

```
    lineEarth.geometry.vertices[0] = new THREE.Vector3(earth.position.x,earth.position.y,earth.position.z);
    //lineEarth.geometry.computeLineDistances();
    lineEarth.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

I also tried uncommenting the computeLineDistances line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you have to recompute the LineDistance for every change in the vertices? just an idea, though :)

Comment: This is what I tried when using the commented line in the update() method, but nothing changes.

Comment: Try `lineEarth.material.attributes.lineDistances.needsUpdate = true;` after you recompute line distances. Also, avoid `new`. Use `lineEarth.geometry.vertices[0].set( x, y, z );`

Comment: Thanks that actually worked, and thanks a lot for the tip. It will optimize all my line updates.

Comment: I tried `lineEarth.material.attributes.lineDistances.needsUpdate = true;`, but I get a `TypeError: lineEarth.material.attributes is undefined`. My web searches failed to produce anything helfpul, this question seems to be the only mention of this issue.

Comment: To add a recent update to this thread, this worked for me: 

geometry.computeLineDistances();
geometry.lineDistancesNeedUpdate = true